# How to add new object to empty json file using the fetch API

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, object, fetch-api

(using Javascript & React)

I'm trying to create a form that allows users to create their own tables, they would specify the table's *name*, *headers* and *data*, and I would use a POST `fetch` method to add it to the json file.
...but it seems like I can only add key:value pairs to existing objects.

for example:
if the JSON file only contains:

```
 {

 }
```

Is it possible to use a `fetch()` post method to populate the file (from user input) with:

```
{
  "title" : [
     {
     "headers" : ...etc,
     "data" : ...etc"
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the right vocabulary or if the thing that the "title" item is representing even has another name, but the emcompassing "`title`" within the JSON file is what I'm having trouble figuring out how to create. I'm trying to avoid any file "read/write" methods, but I'm not sure if it's possible to add an item to an
~empty json file any other way, specifically with fetch().

I try to fetch from the server's URL, "`localhost:3000`" (no URI), and when I try to post I get a "`net::ERR_SSL_PROTCOL_ERROR"`.

it seems like the json file is an object itself (since anything in the file would be wrapped in `{`brackets`}`), and just as I would post to a pre-existing item within the json file (such as "`title`" would be), then I'd also be able to post to the json file itself. Please help me understand why I can use a fetch-post method to add key:value pairs to existing objects within the json file but why I can't add "title" to the json file itself.

---

This is my fetch request that is giving me the error. I actually had to try to recreate the "body:" portion but I am having trouble, I've tried so many variations and didn't bother to keep track of it, I'm sure there's some kind of syntax error in the body rn but I've tried recreating it a bunch to no avail, so I hope this still gives you an idea of what *was* giving me problems.

```
function post() {    
    fetch("http://localhost:3000", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            {title}: [],
        }),
        headers: {"content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
    })
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Do you have a server with a route set up to handle the POST request?

Comment: I have no problems accessing server data when it's already existing, and I can post to that same data, but I can not create it from scratch.

Comment: just posted the fetch portion of the code, the db.json file is just empty except for those brackets, "{ }".

Comment: It's not clear what your are doing on server side, reading your question it seems like your are trying to write directly content to a static file with a post request, is that it ?

Comment: I suppose that is what I'm trying to do lol. But doesn't the post request do that anyway?

Comment: No, a POST request does of course not just arbitrarily change the content of files on your server. If that was the case, then I could overwrite any file on your server, just by making a POST request to the file's URL ...

Comment: lol, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a static file this way.

A static files server will accept only `GET` requests and responds with the files contents. If you need to handle `POST` requests (or any of `PUT`, `DELETE` etc..) you need to write a server application (a REST API) and define the routes to handle your posts. You have to write the service that handle the request, get the data, extract the file content, update it with the request data and write it back to the file.